# Does enabling handoff (universal clipboard) subject copied items to arbitrary upload?

Tags: continuity, macos

From a security perspective in dealing with passwords, encryption keys, etc -- does enabling handoff subject my copied items (e.g. cmd+c) to be arbitrarily uploaded to Apple's handoff services?

Any excerpts from terms & conditions or developer docs also provide helpful solutions. I realize Apple tends to keep implementation details like this unavailable to the public.

Comment: Universal Clipboard isn't going to know what that text is, unless it's tagged some way.  Password managers like 1Password tag clipboard items with an attribute that can be inspected, but if you're just copying arbitrary text from say an Excel spreadsheet, that wouldn't be happening.  One of the reasons I use [Maccy](https://github.com/p0deje/Maccy) as a clipboard manager is that it explicitly talks about that, and that it does not copy such text.

Comment: It's done locally over Bluetooth -- it doesn't go to Apple's Servers, if that's what you're asking. What protections there are against 'eavesdropping', I don't know.

Comment: @benwiggy can you cite a source and throw it in an answer? I'd mark it as solution